What are the alternatives for azure keyvault to securely store secrets?
I have an application which accesses Azure Key Vault for retrieving secrets.
As per the pricing calculator as number of requests increase there will be a bill from azure. Here I can see that the number of requests is huge as the keys required during the authentications are all stored in Key Vault.
Is there any way to store the freequently accessed secrets in some other places?
Is it possible to store secrets in app settings? If so, how safe is that from a security perspective?

Is it possible to store secrets in app settings? - no, you don't want to do that. The right place to store secrets is Azure Keyvault if your applications are hosted on Azure. Just out of curiosity, what exactly is a huge number of requests? Secrets operations cost $0.03/10,000 transactions - that doesn't look that expensive.

@RuiJarimba Thanks for the quick response. May be I am confused. I saw the same  cost $0.03/10,000 in pricing calculator. But may I know one thing, what this transaction mean? If I read a secret, will that be one transaction? If so depending on the number of users and number of devices, I can see a huge number.


You can find an option to store the secrets of Azure Keyvault in Azure App Service Application Settings and  Azure App Configuration.

Navigate to the Azure App Service => Environment Variables => Application Settings


Azure App Service:


Save the key-value pair as a key vault reference.

Azure App Configuration:


If so, how safe is that from a security perspective?

But it is not a recommended way, as it has risk of exposing the secrets to the users who have access to the Application.

Another option I found is storing them in Storage Account => Encryption.


Thanks @Rui Jarimba for the comments.
Yes, as mentioned by Rui, the better and safe way is to store them in the Key Vault itself.
